# Porcentaje acumulado

Tags: powerbi

Muy buena tarde

Podria alguien indicarme como puedo obtener en Power BI las siguientes funciones:

Objetivo  Cantidad  %Cumplimiento    %Cumplimiento de objetivo     %Acumulado   Meses
22          3             14%                  1%                      1%        Enero
33          4             12%                  1%                      2%        Febrero
44          22                                                                   Marzo
55          33
66          12
77          55
88          17

%Cumplimiento Se obtiene de la cantidad divida el objetivo
%Cumplimiento de objetivo Se obtiene cada valor de cantidad dividido el total del objetivo (385)
%Acumulado es el porcentaje acumulado mes a mes.

He tratado en Power BI pero no pude obtener los valores de %Cumplimiento de objetivo y     %Acumulado.

Podria por favor alguien ayudarme a crear las funciones en DAX

Comment: [No dupliques preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/609662)...

Comment: Además, muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido.