# Formula DAX para porcentajes

Tags: powerbi

Muy buena tarde

Podria alguien indicarme como puedo obtener en Power BI las siguientes funciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las columnas Meses, objetivos y recuento estan en tablas distintas. Recuento es el resultado de un Count.

%Cumplimiento Se obtiene de la cantidad divida el objetivo
%Cumplimiento de objetivo Se obtiene cada valor de cantidad dividido el total del objetivo (385)
%Acumulado es el porcentaje acumulado mes a mes.

He tratado en Power BI pero no pude obtener los valores de %Cumplimiento de objetivo y %Acumulado.

Podria por favor alguien ayudarme a crear las funciones en DAX